# Iterate calculations of different length

Tags: r, loops

I have an n*2 df, with starting month in the first column and monthly returns in the second (sample below). The dates are in year-mon form using the zoo package.

I'd like to calculate the 1 to 12 month returns beginning with each starting month return and use those to create an n*13 dataframe, with the compounded returns making up the last 12 columns (Col 2: 1m return, Col 3: 2m return, ...Col 13: 12m return).

To calculate returns, I am using a simple cumprod:

```
allreturns= function (x) {
  cumprod(1+x/100)-1 }
```

My question is: is there a clever way to use apply and lapply to iterate this function both by length going down the returns column (cumprod of 1:12 every time) and by the starting month? It seems like this would involve a for loop for all the return values (something like {for (i in length(sample$monthlyreturns)), but I'd prefer to do it in a better way.

Thank you for your help!

```
structure(list(startmonth = structure(c(2005, 2005.08333333333, 
2005.16666666667, 2005.25, 2005.33333333333, 2005.41666666667, 
2005.5, 2005.58333333333, 2005.66666666667, 2005.75, 2005.83333333333, 
2005.91666666667, 2006, 2006.08333333333, 2006.16666666667, 2006.25, 
2006.33333333333, 2006.41666666667, 2006.5, 2006.58333333333, 
2006.66666666667, 2006.75, 2006.83333333333, 2006.91666666667
), class = "yearmon"), monthlyreturns = c(7.60884596500546, 4.31712970370427, 
1.7181678651832, 4.86275367671624, 8.06177110411227, 8.07952171890065, 
7.45263583026826, 9.86292108893394, 4.06634262995794, 2.36454397207126, 
9.12716506049037, 3.72667369898409, 1.2204843852669, 7.80610600719228, 
0.640116988215595, 6.94793848553672, 1.73743493855, 2.57189674302936, 
4.7653386532329, 1.79362375289202, 7.56623527035117, 2.70907687023282, 
4.45359382545575, 5.50409059040248)), .Names = c("startmonth", 
"monthlyreturns"), row.names = c(NA, 24L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: What's wrong with a `for` loop?  ... other than that you should be able to calculate the 1 to 12-month return values via some financial functions (plenty available via `CRAN`) directly.  BTW, since each row of your input starts with a different month, do you want the output columns to be zero for previous months,  or is the intent that each row covers a different forward-projection time period?

Comment: plyr is prettier and faster, imo. Sorry I should have specified: i'd like each output column to be month forward regardless of start month. so for Jan 2005 the next column over would be through Feb 2005, for Feb 2005 the 2nd column would be through Mar 2005, and so on.

Comment: OK, so if you've time-tested both a `for` loop and `plyr`, go ahead and answer w/ your solution :-)

Comment: General statement...currently trying to get a for loop to work for this example.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand exactly what you're asking for but would something like the following do it? Your data are in the returns matrix.

```
cum_ret <- rollapply(returns[,2], width=12, FUN = function(x) cumprod(1+x/100)-1 )
cum_ret <- data.frame(Date=returns[1:nrow(cum_ret),1], cum_mon_ret=cum_ret)
dates <- seq(as.Date(cum_ret$Date[1]), by = "month", length.out=nrow(returns))
col_lines <- rainbow(nrow(cum_ret))
plot(dates[1:12], cum_ret[1,-1], xlim=c(dates[1], tail(dates,1)), col=col_lines[1], type="b", pch=19, , ylab="Cummulative Returns", xaxt="n")
for( i_plot in 2:nrow(cum_ret)) lines(dates[i_plot:(11 +i_plot)], cum_ret[i_plot,-1], col=col_lines[i_plot], type="b", pch=19 )
axis.Date(1, at=dates, format="%b-%y")
grid( length(dates) + 1 )
```

Cummulative 12 month returns from each starting month would be

[image]

Comment: Be helpful to post the output your code generates from the OP's source data :-)